# In the Compton effect, the spin of the electron can influence the polarisation of the resulting photon?

Tags: radioactivity

I'm new here! I am trying to demonstrate what is the influence of spin-down (Helicity -1) of photons in radiotherapy using LINACs.

The question is, when an electron interacts with a photon in a process such as the Compton effect, the spin of the electron can influence the polarisation of the resulting photon, but it does not change the fact that the photon remains a massless, self-charged particle.

In other words, if an electron was spin down, its resulting photon will also be or will be more likely to be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this link from CERN https://indico.cern.ch/event/792465/contributions/3566552/attachments/1950927/3238657/Poster.pdf may help you. BUT note that photons are point elementary particles of zero charge , your "fact that the photon remains a massless, self-charged particle." is not correct. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle

Comment: oki thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one theory as follows on how the ancient DC-based LINACs had a bug success considering the malignant cells have more likely positive membrane potential, and healthy ones, negative. Here is my theory I would like to demonstrate (too long so I use pastebin): https://pastebin.com/raw/BVPg1Bi3

Comment: This is a site for simple answers to physics questions based on mainstream theories, not a peer review site, where you should try your theories.